# I want to make portion of the text bold, italic and underline certain text and also give a new line in a paragraph using crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am able to get bold/italic/underline in a paragraph. But cannot get a new line.

I am using a formula

```
 long_text= If {col1}='SPAN' then 'string1' + chrw(13) + 'string2' + ChrW(13) + 'string3' + ChrW(13) else 'string4'
```

I am using another formula

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(long_text,"string1","<i>string1</i>"),
"string2 ","<b>string2 </b>"),
 "string3","<u>string3 </u>");
```

In the format field I am using HTML text.
Then the whole text is wrapped in to single paragraph. The new line from formula is gone.
How can I get 2 things in 1 formula?

Answer (score 0):

If the final output is shown with "HTML" text interpretation, the line breaks can be achieved with `<br>`. That means, you should try to replace your Chr(13) by this string `<br>` in your last formula.